# rails 3.1 paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file-upload, ruby-on-rails-3.1, paperclip

I am getting started with the paperclip plugin, but I can't seem to get an image to show up in development. I added the following to my config/environments/development.rb file:

```
Paperclip.options[:command_path] = "/usr/local/bin/"
```

I installed imagemagick and ghostscript through the homebrew package manager. I then added the paperclip gem to my gemfile and ran bundle install. I then ran

```
rails g paperclip carrier_data asset
rake db:migrate
```

I then went to my carrier data model and added

```
has_attached_file :asset
```

After that I altered the form partial to add the resulting code so I could upload images, I am using the simple form gem and this is the following code that I have entered.

```
<%= simple_form_for [:carrier_datum, @carrier_datum], :url => carrier_datum_path, :html => { :multipart => true} do |f| %>
<div>   
  <%= f.input :asset, :as => :file, :label => "Upload File" %>
</div>
```

Finally I went to the show page and added the following code so I could view the image:

```
<%= image_tag @carrier_datum.asset.url %>
```

When I try to create a new carrier datum record I get this message:

```
No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"carrier_data"}
```

The logs look like the following:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"carrier_data"}):
1: <%= simple_form_for [:carrier_datum, @carrier_datum], :url => carrier_datum_path, :html => { :multipart => true} do |f| %>
2:   <% if @carrier_datum.errors.any? %>
3:     <div id="error_explanation">
4:       <h2><%= pluralize(@carrier_datum.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this carrier_datum from being saved:</h2>
app/views/carrier_data/_form.html.erb:1:in    `_app_views_carrier_data__form_html_erb__2372678434167691626_2513245300'
app/views/carrier_data/new.html.erb:3:in `_app_views_carrier_data_new_html_erb___55769200685419080_2513267980'
app/controllers/carrier_data_controller.rb:30:in `new'
```

I am running rails 3.1, with postgresql as my database if that helps at all.

Here is the output of rake routes

```
carrier_data GET    /carrier_data(.:format)           {:action=>"index", :controller=>"carrier_data"}
                     POST   /carrier_data(.:format)           {:action=>"create", :controller=>"carrier_data"}
   new_carrier_datum GET    /carrier_data/new(.:format)       {:action=>"new", :controller=>"carrier_data"}
  edit_carrier_datum GET    /carrier_data/:id/edit(.:format)  {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"carrier_data"}
       carrier_datum GET    /carrier_data/:id(.:format)       {:action=>"show", :controller=>"carrier_data"}
                     PUT    /carrier_data/:id(.:format)       {:action=>"update", :controller=>"carrier_data"}
                     DELETE /carrier_data/:id(.:format)       {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"carrier_data"}
               pages GET    /pages(.:format)
```

If I remove the simple form call and use regular form partial notation like this:

```
<%= form_for(@carrier_datum, :html => { :multipart => true}) do |f| %>
<div>   
    <%= f.label :asset, "Upload File:"%>
    <%= f.file_field :asset %>
</div>
```

I still get the broken image issue, and my logs say that the image is missing.

Comment: Does the rake routes output match your expectations?

Comment: yes, take a look above to see what the rake routes command gives me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up switching to [carrierwave](https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave), and I must say it it a much better gem for file uploads. If you are working on rails 3.1 it is a better file upload solution.

Answer (score 0):

In the model you need to specify where to put uploaded files

For example:

```
has_attached_file :asset,
:url  => "/assets/:id/:basename.:extension",
:path => ":rails_root/public/assets/:id/:basename.:extension"
```

In the public folder of rails, create a folder "assets".

Each upload will create folders inside with an id and the file uploaded.

Comment: Hmm i copied and pasted those lines to my model and restarted my server and I am still getting the same error.